# How to retrieve resource availability when creating recurring event?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I'm using the `Calendar API` for my application and I have recurring events in it. The problem is that when I'm creating an `event`, I don't know if the selected resource(`room`) is available for all recurrences of the event - I know only if the `room` is available for today. So when I create a recurring event and for some instances the room is busy, the resource is declining my event. I saw that in `Google Calendar`, there is a button for checking if the room is available for future dates, so probably there is a way to check that. I'll be very grateful for any suggestions for my case.

Answer (score 0):

The easest way to do this would be to try to create the event if it fails then tell the user it failed.

Other wise you could download all the events on the calendar and scan though them from now until the end of time to check if the room is booked before creating the event.  Also hoping that no one books a room while you are doing your download and scanning.

Option two will probably result in more calls to the api than just the single fail call.

The api does not have a check option if thats what you were hoping for.

Comment: Option one - I don't think that there is a way to do the fail check while you are creating an event. You can see that it failed after you've created the event, retrieved it and checked the response status of the resource attendee. So I'll have to make more calls to the API in both options :( Anyways thank you for the help.